# Multi-line regex with multiple matches and negative conditions in python

Tags: python, regex

I am reading a text file and attempting to capture one of the arguments of each distinct tag, which has not been commented out.

More specifically, I have the following input...

```
maybe there is some text \THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{WANT0}
% \THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{NOTWANT}
% blah blah \THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{NOTWANT}
\THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{WANT1}\THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{WANT2}\\stuff
\sometag{stuff I don't want}[{\THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{WANT3}}]{more stuff I don't want}
\THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{OBV_WANT}
```

I want the following output

```
WANT0
WANT1
WANT2
WANT3
OBV_WANT
```

So far I have the following code, which doesn't accomplish what I want

```
with open(target, "r") as ins:
    f = re.findall(r'^(?:[^%])?\\THISTAG\[.+\]{(.+?)}(?:{.+})?', ins.read(),re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Can you tell us what you get instead?

Comment: Sure... I get `OBV_WANT` and nothing else.

Comment: the condition is not clear. It's hard for me to make the regex you want. I can get all the `WANT,` and `OBV_WANT` but I also get the `NOTWANT`. Please make the question clearer

Comment: How is this not clear? I don't want the `NOTWANT` because the line has been commented with `%` in the beginning of the line!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do the regex line by line with filtering out the ones that start with `%`:

```
import re

res = []
with open('test.txt') as f:
    res = sum([re.findall('\\THISTAG\[.*?\]{(.*?)}', line) 
               for line in f if not line.startswith('%')
              ], [])

    print res # ['WANT0', 'WANT1', 'WANT2', 'WANT3', 'OBV_WANT']
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
^%.*|\\THISTAG[^{]+{([^}]+)}
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xU9jT3/1)

**Explanation:**
`^`: Start of string or start of line depending on multiline mode [sample](https://regex101.com/r/jG7wZ9/1)
`.`: Any character except line break [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wY6xS4/1)
`*`: Zero or more times [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wE3zV2/1)
`|`: Alternation / OR operand [sample](https://regex101.com/r/uQ0iC0/1)
`\`: Escapes a special character [sample](https://regex101.com/r/aM5iM5/1)
`[^x]`: One character that is not x [sample](https://regex101.com/r/bB0vG6/1)
`+`: One or more [sample](https://regex101.com/r/wV7cV2/1)
( … )`: Capturing group [sample](https://regex101.com/r/qL1pP8/1)

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^%.*|\\THISTAG[^{]+{([^}]+)}', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"maybe there is some text \THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{WANT0}\n% \THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{NOTWANT}\n% blah blah \THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{NOTWANT}\n\THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{WANT1}\THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{WANT2}\\stuff\n\sometag{stuff I don't want}[{\THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{WANT3}}]{more stuff I don't want}\n\THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{OBV_WANT}"

g = re.findall(p, test_str)
for m in g:
    if m:
        print m
```

Output:

```
WANT0
WANT1
WANT2
WANT3
OBV_WANT
```

Comment: May I ask for a bit more elaborate explanation?

Comment: I can't get this to return `WANT2` when I do `re.findall('(?:^|\G)(?!%).*?\\THISTAG[^{]+{([^}]+)}', ins.read(), re.MULTILINE)`

Comment: Python doesn't support `\G`, see [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wJ5pI9/1#python) with Python as flavor.

Answer (score 1):

So here's your regex shortened up a little bit:

```
re.findall(r'\\THISTAG\[.+?\]{([^N].+?)}', a,re.MULTILINE)
```

The important part is here:

```
{([^N].+?)}
```

Where I have `[^N]` is where you need to make your distinction between what you want and don't want. With the arguments you've given, I get this output:

```
>>> print(a)
\THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{WANT0}
% \THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{NOTWANT}
% blah blah \THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{NOTWANT}
\THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{WANT1}\THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{WANT2}\stuff
\sometag{stuff I don't want}[{\THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{WANT3}}]{more stuff I don'    t want}
\THISTAG[arg1=1,argtwo]{OBV_WANT}
>>>
>>> re.findall(r'\\THISTAG\[.+?\]{([^N].+?)}', a,re.MULTILINE)
['WANT0', 'WANT1', 'WANT2', 'WANT3', 'OBV_WANT']
```

Comment: It does indeed work the way you have defined it in your answer. However, it doesn't work when reading the actual file, the comments do not get ignored.

Comment: Also, I don't understand how you are getting it to ignore the first two comments in the first place.

Comment: Ah I am sorry. I did not understand that "%" was supposed to be a comment. niemmi's answer is probably best for what you want. You could try negative lookbehinds, but since you don't have fixed length they wont really work. Example:  re.findall(r'(?<!% )\\THISTAG\[.+?\]{(.+?)}', a, re.MULTILINE)